# (Urgent) NSolve not working and visualization of solutions

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, visualization, numerical-value

I want to solve a system of three equations and 3 variables numerically with NSolve, but it either takes an eternity and doesn't give me a result or it gives me an error message that the methods NSolve uses are not suitable.

It is just one line:

```
SolTest = 
 NSolve[{gndotFlow, \[Lambda]dotFLow, paldotFLow} == 
   0, {gn, \[Lambda], pal}, Reals]
```

I broadly know the range of the couplings (gn and lambda are larger than 0, lambda not higher than 1/2, gn probably not higher than 2). Can someone help me? It its really urgent and I'm not sure why these seemingly simple equations cannot be solved...

Also, visualising the results via StreamPlot3D would be nice, but I apparently need version 12.3 for that (only have 12.0). Does anyone have an idea for an alternate I might try out?

Here also the 3 equations (they are rather lengthy):

````
{gndotFlow, \[Lambda]dotFLow, paldotFLow}={-((2 gn (-1 + (37 gn)/(540 pal \[Pi]) - (1/(3240 pal \[Pi]^2))
        gn^2 (-1818 + 40/(-1 + 2 \[Lambda]) + (1200 (2 + pal))/(
           pal (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])) - (
           300 (8 + 16 \[Lambda] + pal (-17 + 2 \[Lambda])))/(
           pal (1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda])^2) + (
           600 (-4 + 8 \[Lambda] + pal (-9 + 2 \[Lambda])))/(
           pal (1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]) (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])) - (
           600 (-20 + 8 \[Lambda] + 5 pal (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])))/(
           pal (1 - 2 \[Lambda])^2) - (
           150 (-48 + 64 \[Lambda] + pal (-27 + 22 \[Lambda])))/(
           pal (1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]) (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])) + (
           8 (144 pal^2 (-261 + 199 \[Lambda]) + (3 - 
                 4 \[Lambda])^2 (-909 + 796 \[Lambda]) + 
              6 pal (5589 - 12228 \[Lambda] + 
                 6368 \[Lambda]^2)))/((-3 + 4 \[Lambda]) (-3 + 
              6 pal + 4 \[Lambda])^2) - (
           600 (-9 + 2 \[Lambda]) ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[
             1 - 2 \[Lambda]]])/(
           Sqrt[pal] (1 - 2 \[Lambda])^(3/2)) + (
           75 (-32 + pal (-54 + 44 \[Lambda])) ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[
             1 - 2 \[Lambda]]])/(
           pal^(3/2) (1 - 2 \[Lambda])^(3/2)) + (
           
           300 Sqrt[6]
             ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]])/(
           Sqrt[pal] Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]])) + (1/(
        24 pal^(3/2) \[Pi]))
        gn (-1 + (37 gn)/(
           540 pal \[Pi])) (60 Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]
             ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]] - 
           Sqrt[6] Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]
             ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]] + 
           2 Sqrt[pal] (-27 + 34 pal + 3 Log[3 - 4 \[Lambda]] - 
              3 Log[3 - 6 pal - 4 \[Lambda]] - 
              30 Log[1 - 2 \[Lambda]] + 
              30 Log[1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]]))))/(1 - (4 gn)/(
      3 \[Pi]) - (1/(1620 pal^(5/2) \[Pi]^2))
      gn^2 ((Sqrt[
            pal] (1200 (3 - 4 \[Lambda])^2 (-1 + 2 \[Lambda]) - 
              6 pal^3 (-4179 + 18456 \[Lambda] - 25436 \[Lambda]^2 + 
                 10480 \[Lambda]^3) + 
              pal^2 (67347 - 186720 \[Lambda] + 260316 \[Lambda]^2 - 
                 239248 \[Lambda]^3 + 83840 \[Lambda]^4) + 
              2 pal (-9576 + 58209 \[Lambda] - 167700 \[Lambda]^2 + 
                 238804 \[Lambda]^3 - 159424 \[Lambda]^4 + 
                 41920 \[Lambda]^5)))/((1 - 2 \[Lambda])^2 (1 + pal - 
              2 \[Lambda]) (-3 + 4 \[Lambda]) (-3 + 6 pal + 
              4 \[Lambda])) - (
         75 (-16 + pal + 14 pal \[Lambda]) ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[
           1 - 2 \[Lambda]]])/(1 - 2 \[Lambda])^(3/2) - (
         150 Sqrt[6]
           pal ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]])/
         Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]) + (1/(540 pal \[Pi]))
      37 gn (-1 + (1/(24 pal^(3/2) \[Pi]))
         gn (-60 Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]
              ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]] + 
            Sqrt[6] Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]
              ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]] + 
            Sqrt[pal] (54 - 40 pal - 3 Log[3 - 4 \[Lambda]] + 
               3 Log[3 - 6 pal - 4 \[Lambda]] + 
               30 Log[1 - 2 \[Lambda]] - 
               30 Log[1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]]))) - (1/(
      24 pal^(3/2) \[Pi]))
      gn (-60 Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]
           ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]] + 
         Sqrt[6] Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]
           ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]] + 
         Sqrt[pal] (54 - 40 pal - 3 Log[3 - 4 \[Lambda]] + 
            3 Log[3 - 6 pal - 4 \[Lambda]] + 
            30 Log[1 - 2 \[Lambda]] - 
            30 Log[1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]])))), (2 (gn/(
      12 \[Pi]) - \[Lambda] + (8 gn \[Lambda])/(3 \[Pi]) + (
      37 gn \[Lambda])/(540 pal \[Pi]) + (1/(51840 pal \[Pi]^2))
      gn^2 (-1818 + 40/(-1 + 2 \[Lambda]) + (1200 (2 + pal))/(
         pal (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])) - (
         300 (8 + 16 \[Lambda] + pal (-17 + 2 \[Lambda])))/(
         pal (1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda])^2) + (
         600 (-4 + 8 \[Lambda] + pal (-9 + 2 \[Lambda])))/(
         pal (1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]) (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])) - (
         600 (-20 + 8 \[Lambda] + 5 pal (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])))/(
         pal (1 - 2 \[Lambda])^2) - (
         150 (-48 + 64 \[Lambda] + pal (-27 + 22 \[Lambda])))/(
         pal (1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]) (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])) + (
         8 (144 pal^2 (-261 + 199 \[Lambda]) + (3 - 
               4 \[Lambda])^2 (-909 + 796 \[Lambda]) + 
            6 pal (5589 - 12228 \[Lambda] + 
               6368 \[Lambda]^2)))/((-3 + 4 \[Lambda]) (-3 + 6 pal + 
            4 \[Lambda])^2) - (
         600 (-9 + 2 \[Lambda]) ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[
           1 - 2 \[Lambda]]])/(Sqrt[pal] (1 - 2 \[Lambda])^(3/2)) + (
         75 (-32 + pal (-54 + 44 \[Lambda])) ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[
           1 - 2 \[Lambda]]])/(pal^(3/2) (1 - 2 \[Lambda])^(3/2)) + (
         300 Sqrt[6]
           ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]])/(
         Sqrt[pal] Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]])) + (1/(3240 pal \[Pi]^2))
      gn^2 \[Lambda] (-1818 + 40/(-1 + 2 \[Lambda]) + (
         1200 (2 + pal))/(pal (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])) - (
         300 (8 + 16 \[Lambda] + pal (-17 + 2 \[Lambda])))/(
         pal (1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda])^2) + (
         600 (-4 + 8 \[Lambda] + pal (-9 + 2 \[Lambda])))/(
         pal (1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]) (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])) - (
         600 (-20 + 8 \[Lambda] + 5 pal (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])))/(
         pal (1 - 2 \[Lambda])^2) - (
         150 (-48 + 64 \[Lambda] + pal (-27 + 22 \[Lambda])))/(
         pal (1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]) (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])) + (
         8 (144 pal^2 (-261 + 199 \[Lambda]) + (3 - 
               4 \[Lambda])^2 (-909 + 796 \[Lambda]) + 
            6 pal (5589 - 12228 \[Lambda] + 
               6368 \[Lambda]^2)))/((-3 + 4 \[Lambda]) (-3 + 6 pal + 
            4 \[Lambda])^2) - (
         600 (-9 + 2 \[Lambda]) ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[
           1 - 2 \[Lambda]]])/(Sqrt[pal] (1 - 2 \[Lambda])^(3/2)) + (
         75 (-32 + pal (-54 + 44 \[Lambda])) ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[
           1 - 2 \[Lambda]]])/(pal^(3/2) (1 - 2 \[Lambda])^(3/2)) + (
         300 Sqrt[6]
           ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]])/(
         Sqrt[pal] Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]])) + (1/(
      25920 pal^(5/2) \[Pi]^2))
      gn^2 ((Sqrt[
            pal] (1200 (3 - 4 \[Lambda])^2 (-1 + 2 \[Lambda]) - 
              6 pal^3 (-4179 + 18456 \[Lambda] - 25436 \[Lambda]^2 + 
                 10480 \[Lambda]^3) + 
              pal^2 (67347 - 186720 \[Lambda] + 260316 \[Lambda]^2 - 
                 239248 \[Lambda]^3 + 83840 \[Lambda]^4) + 
              2 pal (-9576 + 58209 \[Lambda] - 167700 \[Lambda]^2 + 
                 238804 \[Lambda]^3 - 159424 \[Lambda]^4 + 
                 41920 \[Lambda]^5)))/((1 - 2 \[Lambda])^2 (1 + pal - 
              2 \[Lambda]) (-3 + 4 \[Lambda]) (-3 + 6 pal + 
              4 \[Lambda])) - (
         75 (-16 + pal + 14 pal \[Lambda]) ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[
           1 - 2 \[Lambda]]])/(1 - 2 \[Lambda])^(3/2) - (
         150 Sqrt[6]
           pal ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]])/
         Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]) + (1/(810 pal^(5/2) \[Pi]^2))
      gn^2 \[Lambda] ((Sqrt[
            pal] (1200 (3 - 4 \[Lambda])^2 (-1 + 2 \[Lambda]) - 
              6 pal^3 (-4179 + 18456 \[Lambda] - 25436 \[Lambda]^2 + 
                 10480 \[Lambda]^3) + 
              pal^2 (67347 - 186720 \[Lambda] + 260316 \[Lambda]^2 - 
                 239248 \[Lambda]^3 + 83840 \[Lambda]^4) + 
              2 pal (-9576 + 58209 \[Lambda] - 167700 \[Lambda]^2 + 
                 238804 \[Lambda]^3 - 159424 \[Lambda]^4 + 
                 41920 \[Lambda]^5)))/((1 - 2 \[Lambda])^2 (1 + pal - 
              2 \[Lambda]) (-3 + 4 \[Lambda]) (-3 + 6 pal + 
              4 \[Lambda])) - (
         75 (-16 + pal + 14 pal \[Lambda]) ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[
           1 - 2 \[Lambda]]])/(1 - 2 \[Lambda])^(3/2) - (
         150 Sqrt[6]
           pal ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]])/
         Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]) - (1/(288 \[Pi]))
      gn (53 + 6/pal - 72/(-3 + 6 pal + 4 \[Lambda]) + 18/(
         pal (-3 + 6 pal + 4 \[Lambda])) - (24 \[Lambda])/(
         pal (-3 + 6 pal + 4 \[Lambda])) + (
         30 (-4 + 8 \[Lambda] + pal (-9 + 2 \[Lambda])))/(
         pal (1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]) (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])) + (
         60 (-2 + pal) ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]])/(
         pal^(3/2) Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]) + (
         24 Sqrt[6]
           ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]])/(
         Sqrt[pal] Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]) + (9 Log[3 - 4 \[Lambda]])/
         pal - (9 Log[3 - 6 pal - 4 \[Lambda]])/pal) (1 - (4 gn)/(
         3 \[Pi]) - (1/(1620 pal^(5/2) \[Pi]^2))
         gn^2 ((Sqrt[
               pal] (1200 (3 - 4 \[Lambda])^2 (-1 + 2 \[Lambda]) - 
                 6 pal^3 (-4179 + 18456 \[Lambda] - 
                    25436 \[Lambda]^2 + 10480 \[Lambda]^3) + 
                 pal^2 (67347 - 186720 \[Lambda] + 
                    260316 \[Lambda]^2 - 239248 \[Lambda]^3 + 
                    83840 \[Lambda]^4) + 
                 2 pal (-9576 + 58209 \[Lambda] - 
                    167700 \[Lambda]^2 + 238804 \[Lambda]^3 - 
                    159424 \[Lambda]^4 + 41920 \[Lambda]^5)))/((1 - 
                 2 \[Lambda])^2 (1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]) (-3 + 
                 4 \[Lambda]) (-3 + 6 pal + 4 \[Lambda])) - (
            75 (-16 + pal + 14 pal \[Lambda]) ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[
              1 - 2 \[Lambda]]])/(1 - 2 \[Lambda])^(3/2) - (
            150 Sqrt[6]
              pal ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]])/
            Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]) + (1/(540 pal \[Pi]))
         37 gn (-1 + (1/(24 pal^(3/2) \[Pi]))
            gn (-60 Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]
                 ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]] + 
               Sqrt[6] Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]
                 ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]] + 
               Sqrt[pal] (54 - 40 pal - 3 Log[3 - 4 \[Lambda]] + 
                  3 Log[3 - 6 pal - 4 \[Lambda]] + 
                  30 Log[1 - 2 \[Lambda]] - 
                  30 Log[1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]]))) - (1/(
         24 pal^(3/2) \[Pi]))
         gn (-60 Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]
              ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]] + 
            Sqrt[6] Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]
              ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]] + 
            Sqrt[pal] (54 - 40 pal - 3 Log[3 - 4 \[Lambda]] + 
               3 Log[3 - 6 pal - 4 \[Lambda]] + 
               30 Log[1 - 2 \[Lambda]] - 
               30 Log[1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]]))) - (1/(
      6480 pal^(5/2) \[Pi]^2))
      37 gn^2 \[Lambda] (-60 Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]
           ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]] + 
         Sqrt[6] Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]
           ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]] + 
         Sqrt[
          pal] (54 - 40 pal - 3 Log[3 - 4 \[Lambda]] + 
            3 Log[3 - 6 pal - 4 \[Lambda]] + 
            30 Log[1 - 2 \[Lambda]] - 
            30 Log[1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]])) + (1/(12 pal^(3/2) \[Pi]))
      gn \[Lambda] (-60 Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]
           ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]] + 
         Sqrt[6] Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]
           ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]] + 
         Sqrt[pal] (54 - 40 pal - 3 Log[3 - 4 \[Lambda]] + 
            3 Log[3 - 6 pal - 4 \[Lambda]] + 
            30 Log[1 - 2 \[Lambda]] - 
            30 Log[1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]])) - (1/(
      1244160 pal^(5/2) \[Pi]^3))
      gn^3 (-1818 + 40/(-1 + 2 \[Lambda]) + (1200 (2 + pal))/(
         pal (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])) - (
         300 (8 + 16 \[Lambda] + pal (-17 + 2 \[Lambda])))/(
         pal (1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda])^2) + (
         600 (-4 + 8 \[Lambda] + pal (-9 + 2 \[Lambda])))/(
         pal (1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]) (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])) - (
         600 (-20 + 8 \[Lambda] + 5 pal (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])))/(
         pal (1 - 2 \[Lambda])^2) - (
         150 (-48 + 64 \[Lambda] + pal (-27 + 22 \[Lambda])))/(
         pal (1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]) (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])) + (
         8 (144 pal^2 (-261 + 199 \[Lambda]) + (3 - 
               4 \[Lambda])^2 (-909 + 796 \[Lambda]) + 
            6 pal (5589 - 12228 \[Lambda] + 
               6368 \[Lambda]^2)))/((-3 + 4 \[Lambda]) (-3 + 6 pal + 
            4 \[Lambda])^2) - (
         600 (-9 + 2 \[Lambda]) ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[
           1 - 2 \[Lambda]]])/(Sqrt[pal] (1 - 2 \[Lambda])^(3/2)) + (
         75 (-32 + pal (-54 + 44 \[Lambda])) ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[
           1 - 2 \[Lambda]]])/(pal^(3/2) (1 - 2 \[Lambda])^(3/2)) + (
         300 Sqrt[6]
           ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]])/(
         Sqrt[pal] Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]])) (-60 Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]
           ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]] + 
         Sqrt[6] Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]
           ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]] + 
         Sqrt[pal] (54 - 40 pal - 3 Log[3 - 4 \[Lambda]] + 
            3 Log[3 - 6 pal - 4 \[Lambda]] + 
            30 Log[1 - 2 \[Lambda]] - 
            30 Log[1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]])) + (1/(
      288 pal^(3/2) \[Pi]^2))
      gn^2 (60 Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]
           ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]] - 
         Sqrt[6] Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]
           ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]] + 
         2 Sqrt[pal] (-27 + 34 pal + 3 Log[3 - 4 \[Lambda]] - 
            3 Log[3 - 6 pal - 4 \[Lambda]] - 
            30 Log[1 - 2 \[Lambda]] + 
            30 Log[1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]])) - (1/(
      12960 pal^(5/2) \[Pi]^2))
      37 gn^2 \[Lambda] (60 Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]
           ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]] - 
         Sqrt[6] Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]
           ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]] + 
         2 Sqrt[pal] (-27 + 34 pal + 3 Log[3 - 4 \[Lambda]] - 
            3 Log[3 - 6 pal - 4 \[Lambda]] - 
            30 Log[1 - 2 \[Lambda]] + 
            30 Log[1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]])) + (1/(24 pal^(3/2) \[Pi]))
      gn \[Lambda] (60 Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]
           ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]] - 
         Sqrt[6] Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]
           ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]] + 
         2 Sqrt[pal] (-27 + 34 pal + 3 Log[3 - 4 \[Lambda]] - 
            3 Log[3 - 6 pal - 4 \[Lambda]] - 
            30 Log[1 - 2 \[Lambda]] + 
            30 Log[1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]])) + (1/(
      622080 pal^4 \[Pi]^3))
      gn^3 ((Sqrt[
            pal] (1200 (3 - 4 \[Lambda])^2 (-1 + 2 \[Lambda]) - 
              6 pal^3 (-4179 + 18456 \[Lambda] - 25436 \[Lambda]^2 + 
                 10480 \[Lambda]^3) + 
              pal^2 (67347 - 186720 \[Lambda] + 260316 \[Lambda]^2 - 
                 239248 \[Lambda]^3 + 83840 \[Lambda]^4) + 
              2 pal (-9576 + 58209 \[Lambda] - 167700 \[Lambda]^2 + 
                 238804 \[Lambda]^3 - 159424 \[Lambda]^4 + 
                 41920 \[Lambda]^5)))/((1 - 2 \[Lambda])^2 (1 + pal - 
              2 \[Lambda]) (-3 + 4 \[Lambda]) (-3 + 6 pal + 
              4 \[Lambda])) - (
         75 (-16 + pal + 14 pal \[Lambda]) ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[
           1 - 2 \[Lambda]]])/(1 - 2 \[Lambda])^(3/2) - (
         150 Sqrt[6]
           pal ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]])/
         Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]) (60 Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]
           ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]] - 
         Sqrt[6] Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]
           ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]] + 
         2 Sqrt[pal] (-27 + 34 pal + 3 Log[3 - 4 \[Lambda]] - 
            3 Log[3 - 6 pal - 4 \[Lambda]] - 
            30 Log[1 - 2 \[Lambda]] + 
            30 Log[1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]])) - (1/(
      288 pal^(3/2) \[Pi]))
      gn ((30 (-4 + pal) ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]])/
         Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]] + (
         12 Sqrt[6]
           pal ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]])/
         Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]] - (
         Sqrt[pal] (120 + 
            52 pal (-1 + 2 \[Lambda]) + (9 - 18 \[Lambda]) Log[
              3 - 4 \[Lambda]] + 
            9 (-1 + 2 \[Lambda]) Log[3 - 6 pal - 4 \[Lambda]]))/(-1 + 
          2 \[Lambda])) (-1 + (37 gn)/(540 pal \[Pi]) - (1/(
         3240 pal \[Pi]^2))
         gn^2 (-1818 + 40/(-1 + 2 \[Lambda]) + (1200 (2 + pal))/(
            pal (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])) - (
            300 (8 + 16 \[Lambda] + pal (-17 + 2 \[Lambda])))/(
            pal (1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda])^2) + (
            600 (-4 + 8 \[Lambda] + pal (-9 + 2 \[Lambda])))/(
            pal (1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]) (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])) - (
            600 (-20 + 8 \[Lambda] + 5 pal (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])))/(
            pal (1 - 2 \[Lambda])^2) - (
            150 (-48 + 64 \[Lambda] + pal (-27 + 22 \[Lambda])))/(
            pal (1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]) (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])) + (
            8 (144 pal^2 (-261 + 199 \[Lambda]) + (3 - 
                  4 \[Lambda])^2 (-909 + 796 \[Lambda]) + 
               6 pal (5589 - 12228 \[Lambda] + 
                  6368 \[Lambda]^2)))/((-3 + 4 \[Lambda]) (-3 + 
               6 pal + 4 \[Lambda])^2) - (
            600 (-9 + 2 \[Lambda]) ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[
              1 - 2 \[Lambda]]])/(
            Sqrt[pal] (1 - 2 \[Lambda])^(3/2)) + (
            75 (-32 + pal (-54 + 44 \[Lambda])) ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[
              1 - 2 \[Lambda]]])/(
            pal^(3/2) (1 - 2 \[Lambda])^(3/2)) + (
            300 Sqrt[6]
              ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]])/(
            Sqrt[pal] Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]])) + (1/(
         24 pal^(3/2) \[Pi]))
         gn (-1 + (37 gn)/(
            540 pal \[Pi])) (60 Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]
              ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]] - 
            Sqrt[6] Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]
              ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]] + 
            2 Sqrt[pal] (-27 + 34 pal + 3 Log[3 - 4 \[Lambda]] - 
               3 Log[3 - 6 pal - 4 \[Lambda]] - 
               30 Log[1 - 2 \[Lambda]] + 
               30 Log[1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]])))))/(1 - (4 gn)/(
    3 \[Pi]) - (1/(1620 pal^(5/2) \[Pi]^2))
    gn^2 ((Sqrt[
          pal] (1200 (3 - 4 \[Lambda])^2 (-1 + 2 \[Lambda]) - 
            6 pal^3 (-4179 + 18456 \[Lambda] - 25436 \[Lambda]^2 + 
               10480 \[Lambda]^3) + 
            pal^2 (67347 - 186720 \[Lambda] + 260316 \[Lambda]^2 - 
               239248 \[Lambda]^3 + 83840 \[Lambda]^4) + 
            2 pal (-9576 + 58209 \[Lambda] - 167700 \[Lambda]^2 + 
               238804 \[Lambda]^3 - 159424 \[Lambda]^4 + 
               41920 \[Lambda]^5)))/((1 - 2 \[Lambda])^2 (1 + pal - 
            2 \[Lambda]) (-3 + 4 \[Lambda]) (-3 + 6 pal + 
            4 \[Lambda])) - (
       75 (-16 + pal + 14 pal \[Lambda]) ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[
         1 - 2 \[Lambda]]])/(1 - 2 \[Lambda])^(3/2) - (
       150 Sqrt[6]
         pal ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]])/
       Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]) + (1/(540 pal \[Pi]))
    37 gn (-1 + (1/(24 pal^(3/2) \[Pi]))
       gn (-60 Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]
            ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]] + 
          Sqrt[6] Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]
            ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]] + 
          Sqrt[pal] (54 - 40 pal - 3 Log[3 - 4 \[Lambda]] + 
             3 Log[3 - 6 pal - 4 \[Lambda]] + 
             30 Log[1 - 2 \[Lambda]] - 
             30 Log[1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]]))) - (1/(
    24 pal^(3/2) \[Pi]))
    gn (-60 Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]
         ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]] + 
       Sqrt[6] Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]
         ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]] + 
       Sqrt[pal] (54 - 40 pal - 3 Log[3 - 4 \[Lambda]] + 
          3 Log[3 - 6 pal - 4 \[Lambda]] + 30 Log[1 - 2 \[Lambda]] - 
          30 Log[1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]]))), (2 (pal + (1/(
      24 Sqrt[pal] \[Pi]))
      gn (60 Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]
           ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]] - 
         Sqrt[6] Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]
           ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]] + 
         2 Sqrt[pal] (-27 + 34 pal + 3 Log[3 - 4 \[Lambda]] - 
            3 Log[3 - 6 pal - 4 \[Lambda]] - 
            30 Log[1 - 2 \[Lambda]] + 
            30 Log[1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]])) + 
      32 gn \[Pi] ((1/(
         138240 \[Pi]^2))(-1818 + 40/(-1 + 2 \[Lambda]) + (
           1200 (2 + pal))/(pal (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])) - (
           300 (8 + 16 \[Lambda] + pal (-17 + 2 \[Lambda])))/(
           pal (1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda])^2) + (
           600 (-4 + 8 \[Lambda] + pal (-9 + 2 \[Lambda])))/(
           pal (1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]) (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])) - (
           600 (-20 + 8 \[Lambda] + 5 pal (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])))/(
           pal (1 - 2 \[Lambda])^2) - (
           150 (-48 + 64 \[Lambda] + pal (-27 + 22 \[Lambda])))/(
           pal (1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]) (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])) + (
           8 (144 pal^2 (-261 + 199 \[Lambda]) + (3 - 
                 4 \[Lambda])^2 (-909 + 796 \[Lambda]) + 
              6 pal (5589 - 12228 \[Lambda] + 
                 6368 \[Lambda]^2)))/((-3 + 4 \[Lambda]) (-3 + 
              6 pal + 4 \[Lambda])^2) - (
           600 (-9 + 2 \[Lambda]) ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[
             1 - 2 \[Lambda]]])/(
           Sqrt[pal] (1 - 2 \[Lambda])^(3/2)) + (
           75 (-32 + pal (-54 + 44 \[Lambda])) ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[
             1 - 2 \[Lambda]]])/(
           pal^(3/2) (1 - 2 \[Lambda])^(3/2)) + (
           300 Sqrt[6]
             ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]])/(
           Sqrt[pal] Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]])) - (1/(
         3317760 pal^(3/2) \[Pi]^3))
         gn (-1818 + 40/(-1 + 2 \[Lambda]) + (1200 (2 + pal))/(
            pal (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])) - (
            300 (8 + 16 \[Lambda] + pal (-17 + 2 \[Lambda])))/(
            pal (1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda])^2) + (
            600 (-4 + 8 \[Lambda] + pal (-9 + 2 \[Lambda])))/(
            pal (1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]) (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])) - (
            600 (-20 + 8 \[Lambda] + 5 pal (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])))/(
            pal (1 - 2 \[Lambda])^2) - (
            150 (-48 + 64 \[Lambda] + pal (-27 + 22 \[Lambda])))/(
            pal (1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]) (-1 + 2 \[Lambda])) + (
            8 (144 pal^2 (-261 + 199 \[Lambda]) + (3 - 
                  4 \[Lambda])^2 (-909 + 796 \[Lambda]) + 
               6 pal (5589 - 12228 \[Lambda] + 
                  6368 \[Lambda]^2)))/((-3 + 4 \[Lambda]) (-3 + 
               6 pal + 4 \[Lambda])^2) - (
            600 (-9 + 2 \[Lambda]) ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[
              1 - 2 \[Lambda]]])/(
            Sqrt[pal] (1 - 2 \[Lambda])^(3/2)) + (
            75 (-32 + pal (-54 + 44 \[Lambda])) ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[
              1 - 2 \[Lambda]]])/(
            pal^(3/2) (1 - 2 \[Lambda])^(3/2)) + (
            300 Sqrt[6]
              ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]])/(
            Sqrt[pal] Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]])) (-60 Sqrt[
             1 - 2 \[Lambda]]
              ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]] + 
            Sqrt[6] Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]
              ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]] + 
            Sqrt[pal] (54 - 40 pal - 3 Log[3 - 4 \[Lambda]] + 
               3 Log[3 - 6 pal - 4 \[Lambda]] + 
               30 Log[1 - 2 \[Lambda]] - 
               30 Log[1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]])) + (1/(
         69120 pal^(
          3/2) \[Pi]^2))((Sqrt[
               pal] (1200 (3 - 4 \[Lambda])^2 (-1 + 2 \[Lambda]) - 
                 6 pal^3 (-4179 + 18456 \[Lambda] - 
                    25436 \[Lambda]^2 + 10480 \[Lambda]^3) + 
                 pal^2 (67347 - 186720 \[Lambda] + 
                    260316 \[Lambda]^2 - 239248 \[Lambda]^3 + 
                    83840 \[Lambda]^4) + 
                 2 pal (-9576 + 58209 \[Lambda] - 
                    167700 \[Lambda]^2 + 238804 \[Lambda]^3 - 
                    159424 \[Lambda]^4 + 41920 \[Lambda]^5)))/((1 - 
                 2 \[Lambda])^2 (1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]) (-3 + 
                 4 \[Lambda]) (-3 + 6 pal + 4 \[Lambda])) - (
            75 (-16 + pal + 14 pal \[Lambda]) ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[
              1 - 2 \[Lambda]]])/(1 - 2 \[Lambda])^(3/2) - (
            150 Sqrt[6]
              pal ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]])/
            Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]) (1 + (1/(24 pal^(3/2) \[Pi]))
            gn (60 Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]
                 ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]] - 
               Sqrt[6] Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]
                 ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]] + 
               2 Sqrt[pal] (-27 + 34 pal + 3 Log[3 - 4 \[Lambda]] - 
                  3 Log[3 - 6 pal - 4 \[Lambda]] - 
                  30 Log[1 - 2 \[Lambda]] + 
                  30 Log[1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]]))))))/(1 - (4 gn)/(
    3 \[Pi]) - (1/(1620 pal^(5/2) \[Pi]^2))
    gn^2 ((Sqrt[
          pal] (1200 (3 - 4 \[Lambda])^2 (-1 + 2 \[Lambda]) - 
            6 pal^3 (-4179 + 18456 \[Lambda] - 25436 \[Lambda]^2 + 
               10480 \[Lambda]^3) + 
            pal^2 (67347 - 186720 \[Lambda] + 260316 \[Lambda]^2 - 
               239248 \[Lambda]^3 + 83840 \[Lambda]^4) + 
            2 pal (-9576 + 58209 \[Lambda] - 167700 \[Lambda]^2 + 
               238804 \[Lambda]^3 - 159424 \[Lambda]^4 + 
               41920 \[Lambda]^5)))/((1 - 2 \[Lambda])^2 (1 + pal - 
            2 \[Lambda]) (-3 + 4 \[Lambda]) (-3 + 6 pal + 
            4 \[Lambda])) - (
       75 (-16 + pal + 14 pal \[Lambda]) ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[
         1 - 2 \[Lambda]]])/(1 - 2 \[Lambda])^(3/2) - (
       150 Sqrt[6]
         pal ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]])/
       Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]) + (1/(540 pal \[Pi]))
    37 gn (-1 + (1/(24 pal^(3/2) \[Pi]))
       gn (-60 Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]
            ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]] + 
          Sqrt[6] Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]
            ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]] + 
          Sqrt[pal] (54 - 40 pal - 3 Log[3 - 4 \[Lambda]] + 
             3 Log[3 - 6 pal - 4 \[Lambda]] + 
             30 Log[1 - 2 \[Lambda]] - 
             30 Log[1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]]))) - (1/(
    24 pal^(3/2) \[Pi]))
    gn (-60 Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]
         ArcTan[Sqrt[pal]/Sqrt[1 - 2 \[Lambda]]] + 
       Sqrt[6] Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]
         ArcTan[(Sqrt[6] Sqrt[pal])/Sqrt[-3 + 4 \[Lambda]]] + 
       Sqrt[pal] (54 - 40 pal - 3 Log[3 - 4 \[Lambda]] + 
          3 Log[3 - 6 pal - 4 \[Lambda]] + 30 Log[1 - 2 \[Lambda]] - 
          30 Log[1 + pal - 2 \[Lambda]])))}
```
````

Comment: Where have you defined gndotFlow, \[Lambda]dotFLow, and paldotFLow? I suggest that you start with a simpler set of equations and learn the proper syntax. Once you are comfortable using NSolve, you may be able to solve the thing you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for the quick remark! I forgot to add that pre-line to the second code paragraph; now it's there and the equations are defined. I tried it out with simpler equations already and it worked, so I'm not sure what might be wrong... Hope you might be able to see where it might have gone wrong.

Comment: `{0,0,0}` works if you allow the following:  `Limit[{gndotFlow, \[Lambda]dotFLow, 
   paldotFLow} /. {gn -> 0, \[Lambda] -> 0}, pal -> 0] = {0,0,0}`.  Although I suspect that isn't a very satisfying solution.  Do you have any idea what the values might be?  Are they all positive?  And can you share why you think there is a solution?

Comment: Thats true, but it's the trivial solution, that doesn't help me. It's an application of the asymptotic safety scenario of quantum gravity (here with the additional coupling pal to the gravitational and cosmological "constant" (/ coupling)). I need so-called non-Gaussian solutions which differ from 0. A solution should in principle exist (from a physics point of view) and I know that gn is definitely larger than 0 (and should be closer to 1 than to 0). lambda could potentially be negative and pal is unknown. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Try `f=SumOfSquaresOfYourThreeEquations;NMinimize[{Abs[f],gn>0&&\[Lambda]>0},{pal,\[Lambda],gn}]` and in a few seconds I get `{4.64531*^-11,{pal->-0.459984,\[Lambda]->0.711265,gn->0.222013}}` and that is within floating point noise of being a solution to your system. You didn't say if `pal` needed to be positive, but you could add that constraint and one trial gave slightly larger noise.  If this isn't good enough then you can fiddle with options like `WorkingPrecision` and see if you can get a ersult that satisfies you.

Comment: `SumOfSquaresOfYourThreeEquations/.gn->0//Simplify` returns `2*(pal+2*λ^2)` which, considering the size of your equations, might be a record for simplification. If you could provide tighter bounds for the ranges of your variables then it might be more likely to find the solution that you are really looking for.